# Simple Javascript error - Form submit doesn't append querystring

Tags: html, forms, query-string

I want to submit a form to a URL appending few values as the querystring.

I am using this to call;

```
    <form id="form1" method="GET" action="http://abc.appspot.com/_ah/xmpp/message/chat/">
    <input type="text" id="data" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

However, when I click on submit button, the URL that is fired is `"http://abc.appspot.com/_ah/xmpp/message/chat/?"`

The value of the "data" is not appended. Am I doing something silly here?

Thanks

Comment: this question hast nothing to do with javascript or jquery.

Comment: in what way are you using jquery or javascript here?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I started off with JQuery first when I started writing this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only fields which have `name` attribute are submited. This makes sense because how would you access those values without some key in POST of GET. So change your code to

```
<input type="text" name="data" id="data" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add name to input text and check

```
<input type="text" id="data" name="data" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Give any form elements that are to be submitted a `name` attribute or they'll be ignored. So:

```
<input type="text" id="data" name="data" />
```

(You don't need the `id` attribute unless you reference it from somewhere else, but it won't hurt.)

Also it probably makes more sense to have `method="POST"` on your form.